# How to set realtime thread in Swift?

Tags: swift, multithreading, real-time

I'm trying to implement the `set_realtime()` function from this [OSX scheduling guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/scheduler/scheduler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-CH211-BABCHEEB) in Swift.

I'm stuck on `thread_policy_set()`. The following causes this compiler error:

> "Cannot specialize a non-generic definition"

I've also tried a couple other things but get various type mismatch errors with `&policy`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
func set_realtime(period: UInt32, computation: UInt32, constraint: UInt32) -> Bool {
    let TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY: UInt32 = 2
    let TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY_COUNT = UInt32(MemoryLayout<thread_time_constraint_policy_data_t>.size / MemoryLayout<integer_t>.size)
    let SUCCESS: Int32 = 0
    var policy: thread_time_constraint_policy
    var ret: Int32
    let thread: thread_port_t = pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self())

    policy.period = period
    policy.computation = computation
    policy.constraint = constraint
    policy.preemptible = 1

    ret = withUnsafeMutablePointer<integer_t>(to: &policy, { ptr -> Int32 in
        thread_policy_set(thread, TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY, ptr, TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY_COUNT)
    })

    if ret != SUCCESS {
        print(stderr, "set_realtime() failed.\n")
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add a type placeholder to `withUnsafeMutablePointer()` to
cast the pointer to a different type. You have to "rebind" the pointer
instead:

```
ret = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &policy) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: Int(TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY_COUNT)) {
        thread_policy_set(thread, TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY, $0, TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY_COUNT)
    }
}
```