# How do I achieve very accurate timing in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, core-audio, timing

I am working on a musical app with an arpeggio/sequencing feature that requires great timing accuracy.  Currently, using `Timer' I have achieved an accuracy with an average jitter of ~5ms, but a max jitter of ~11ms, which is unacceptable for fast arpeggios of 8th, 16th notes & 32nd notes especially.

I've read the 'CADisplayLink' is more accurate than 'Timer', but since it is limited to 1/60th of a second for it's accuracy (~16-17ms), it seems like it would be a less accurate approach than what I've achieved with `Timer`.

Would diving into CoreAudio be the only way to achieve what I want?  Is there some other way to achieve more accurate timing?

Comment: See [Technical Note TN2169](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2169/_index.html)

Comment: Try to use NSTimeInterval https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583263/measuring-time-accurately-in-swift-for-comparison-across-devices

Comment: @PlateReverb - No, I haven't see anything in particular, but it certainly should be possible. I'd suggest giving it a go and posting if you have any problems. BTW, before you go into this, you might want to experiment with GCD timer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39581096/1271826), using a queue with the highest priority and a zero leeway

Comment: Having said all of that, I might suggest diving into the CoreAudio API to see if it can do what you want. I wonder if they've already solved your problem...

Comment: One final observation, but you didn't say macOS or iOS, but if the latter, I'd make sure to do your tests on a physical device. And when benchmarking, make sure you use a release build with optimizations turned on.

Comment: The iPhone is a media playback device, with iOS thus optimized. On an iPhone 7, a foreground app can get reliable Audio Unit buffer callbacks of 16 samples, which is less than a 1/3 mS max buffer jitter.  If you mix in your percussion samples at an exact sample count offset (at a 48k sample rate), your jitter is down to less than 2.1 uS.  Thus, my preference for using Core Audio directly.

Comment: To what real-time output is your rhythmic timing relative?

Comment: Your jitter source might be from violating one of the 4 rules for any real-time periodic timer code.  See: http://atastypixel.com/blog/four-common-mistakes-in-audio-development/#four-rules

Comment: @hotpaw2 I apologize for the very late reply.  I focused on other parts of my app this past year, but I'm ready to solve this timing issue with Core Audio or AVFoundation.  Everything else in my app (sequencer code in Swift & synthesis engines in libpd/pure data) is finished.  Since Core Audio is aimed for doing everything, and all I need is a reliable timer (I assume) to solve my sequencer lag & jitter issues... could you give me more specific advice on how to use Core Audio or AVFoundation to generate a reliable clock for my app's sequencer?  Thank you!

Comment: Generating a clock isn't reliably accurate due to uP threading and dispatch issues.  Core audio works on a pull model, so you might need sequenced and synthesized buffers of raw PCM samples available (slightly) ahead of time so they can be pulled (copied to mixer inputs) by millisecond real-time callbacks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For acceptable musically accurate rhythms, the only suitable timing source is using Core Audio or AVFoundation.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  No matter how accurate your timers are, they're still firing on an unrelated thread that will inevitably be ahead or behind the audio thread.

Comment: @dave234 Could you say if either Core Audio or AVFoundation would offer more accurate timing?  Are they equally "low level" and precise?

Comment: They aren’t equally low level.  AVFoundation is almost certainly built on top of Core Audio.  I’d say they are equally precise though for most contexts.  You have to think in terms of “scheduling” audio, which both APIs support.

Comment: I've only used Core Audio for sub-millisecond sample-accurate rhythm generation. But there appear to be newer AVFoundation APIs that allow this as well.

Comment: Any advice on what Core Audio APIs to look at for reliable timing?  Since I have all my audio generated through libpd/Pure Data, I just need my sequencer Swift code to trigger notes with sample accurate timing (<1ms lag & jitter).  I've been reading through my Core Audio book, and googling for similar examples, but I'm still pretty lost as to how to approach/solve this problem with Core Audio...

Comment: It appears that Swift currently can not be triggered with sub-millisecond accurate timing.  In a WWDC 2017 session, Apple said not to use Swift for audio hard real-time code.  I use memcpy (which is a C lib routine).

Answer (score 10):

I did some testing of `Timer` and `DispatchSourceTimer` (aka GCD timer) on iPhone 7 with 1000 data points with an interval of 0.05 seconds. I was expecting GCD timer to be appreciably more accurate (given that it had a dedicated queue), but I found that they were comparable, with standard deviation of my various trials ranging from 0.2-0.8 milliseconds and maximum deviation from the mean of about 2-8 milliseconds.

When trying `mach_wait_until` as outlined in [Technical Note TN2169: High Precision Timers in iOS / OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2169/_index.html), I achieved a timer that was roughly 4 times as accurate than what I achieved with either `Timer` or GCD timers.

Having said that, I'm not entirely confident of the `mach_wait_until` is the best approach, as the determination of the specific policy values for `thread_policy_set` seem to be poorly documented. But the code below reflects the values I used in my tests, using code adapted from [How to set realtime thread in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336005/how-to-set-realtime-thread-in-swift/43336434) and [TN2169](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2169/_index.html):

```
var timebaseInfo = mach_timebase_info_data_t()

func configureThread() {
    mach_timebase_info(&timebaseInfo)
    let clock2abs = Double(timebaseInfo.denom) / Double(timebaseInfo.numer) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)

    let period      = UInt32(0.00 * clock2abs)
    let computation = UInt32(0.03 * clock2abs) // 30 ms of work
    let constraint  = UInt32(0.05 * clock2abs)

    let THREAD_TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY_COUNT = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout<thread_time_constraint_policy>.size / MemoryLayout<integer_t>.size)

    var policy = thread_time_constraint_policy()
    var ret: Int32
    let thread: thread_port_t = pthread_mach_thread_np(pthread_self())

    policy.period = period
    policy.computation = computation
    policy.constraint = constraint
    policy.preemptible = 0

    ret = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &policy) {
        $0.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: Int(THREAD_TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY_COUNT)) {
            thread_policy_set(thread, UInt32(THREAD_TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY), $0, THREAD_TIME_CONSTRAINT_POLICY_COUNT)
        }
    }

    if ret != KERN_SUCCESS {
        mach_error("thread_policy_set:", ret)
        exit(1)
    }
}
```

I then could do:

```
private func nanosToAbs(_ nanos: UInt64) -> UInt64 {
    return nanos * UInt64(timebaseInfo.denom) / UInt64(timebaseInfo.numer)
}

private func startMachTimer() {
    Thread.detachNewThread {
        autoreleasepool {
            self.configureThread()

            var when = mach_absolute_time()
            for _ in 0 ..< maxCount {
                when += self.nanosToAbs(UInt64(0.05 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
                mach_wait_until(when)

                // do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, you might want to see if `when` hasn't already passed (you want to make sure that your timers don't get backlogged if your processing can't be completed in the allotted time), but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

Anyway, with `mach_wait_until`, I achieved greater fidelity than `Timer` or GCD timers, at the cost of CPU/power consumption as described in [What are the do's and dont's of code running with high precision timers?](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2169/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013172-CH1-TNTAG11000)

I appreciate your skepticism on this final point, but I suspect it would be prudent to dive into CoreAudio and see if it might offer a more robust solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can easily quantify that for you. It's likely to be partially a function of what policy values you use, anyway.

Comment: There's an example in [TN2169: Which timing API(s) should I use?](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2169/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013172-CH1-TNTAG8000). I've revised my question with Swift example, too.

Comment: Any notes on how to stop the timer? I want my timer to run indefinitely (using it for a metronome), so I'm setting `maxCount` fairly high.

What I'm doing now is checking `if (metronome.isOn) { 
 // do something
} else { break }`

Comment: Where it says "do something", you could presumably just `return` if some criterion is met (e.g. check some status property of what have you). Or replace that `for` loop with `while` loop and check your property there...

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on a sequencer App myself, and I would defiantly recommend using AudioKit for those purposes.
It has a its own sequencer class.
https://audiokit.io/

Comment: You should give more example~